# Checking whether value in current row of pandas Series is in lagging window

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame similar to the one generated by this code:

```
names = ['steve', 'bob', 'harry', 'jeff'] * 5
df = pd.DataFrame(
    index=pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2018-10-10', end='2018-10-29', freq='D'), 
    data={'value': [x for x in range(20)],
          'names': names,
         }
)
df['roll'] = np.random.randint(1, 6, df.shape[0])
```

Which produces data that looks like this:

```
            value  names  roll
2018-10-10      0  steve     2
2018-10-11      1    bob     5
2018-10-12      2  harry     4
2018-10-13      3   jeff     2
2018-10-14      4  steve     2
2018-10-15      5    bob     4
2018-10-16      6  harry     1
2018-10-17      7   jeff     2
2018-10-18      8  steve     3
2018-10-19      9    bob     3
...
```

I'd like to add another column `result` that is boolean, grouped by names and true when the value of roll in the current row appears within a 10-day lagging window. I.e. I want this:

```
            value  names  roll  result
2018-10-10      0  steve     2   False
2018-10-11      1    bob     5   False
2018-10-12      2  harry     4   False
2018-10-13      3   jeff     2   False
2018-10-14      4  steve     2    True
2018-10-15      5    bob     4   False
2018-10-16      6  harry     1   False
2018-10-17      7   jeff     2    True
2018-10-18      8  steve     3    True
2018-10-19      9    bob     3   False
...
```

I've tried this:

```
df['result'] = (
    df.groupby('names').apply(lambda x: x['roll'].isin(x.shift().rolling('10D')['roll']))
)
```

which feels logical to me, but I get a `NotImplementedError` that points me here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11704.

Is there a pandas-native way to get where I want to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `rolling` here is no needed

```
df.reset_index().groupby(['names','roll'])['index'].diff().dt.days<10
Out[49]: 
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
6    False
7     True
8    False
9    False
Name: index, dtype: bool
```